# adb no permissions error suddenly

Tags: android, adb, udev, dragonboard

I have been working on the **Snapdragon Dragonboard** for a few days now. I had been able to set it up and even push some applications onto it and run them. Needless to say, the commands adb shell and adb devices gave me some meaningful outputs. But today, I am not able to detect the device, adb shell gives me a no sufficient permissions error and adb devices gives me

```
????????? no devices
```

The instructions that I followed at the beginning of working with this board told me to include the line:
`0x05c6; 0x0956`
in the `adb_usb.ini` in the `~/.android` folder.

However, I saw some better documentation today which asked me to include the line 
`SUBSYSTEM=="usb",SYSFS{idVendor}=="05c6",MODE="0666”`

I replaced SYSFS with ATTR coz I read somewhere that the recent udev needs ATTR instead of SYSFS

I perform:

```
chmod a+r 51-android.rules
sudo stop udev
sudo start udev
android update adb
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

and I get the same result! Still no permissions. What is going wrong? 
Btw, the lsusb gives me a Qualcomm entry. When the usb is unplugged, the lsusb command does not give me a Qualcomm entry.
How can the behavior change overnight?

Comment: had you opened two work spaces at a time. it may create problem some times.

Comment: yeah.. multiple workspaces. But I found a solution: instead of adb kill-server and adb start-server, I tried sudo adb kill-server and sudo adb start-server. somehow this works

Comment: Ok.. post as answer.. it may helpful to some other ..

Comment: try checking setting on your phone. Like usb debugging is on or not and third party applications is checked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of:

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

I tried:

`sudo adb kill-server`

`sudo adb start-server`

somehow this works. I dont know why.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your udev rule is broken and at one point you started the adb daemon as the root user. This is pretty easy to do accidentally since executing adb with any command will launch the daemon if it isn't already started. Using the root user to manually launch the daemon is fine as workaround, but tools like Eclipse that automatically start the service will still attempt to as an unprivileged user (which will cause the reported problem). The proper fix is to follow the official steps under [Configuring USB Access](http://s.android.com/source/initializing.html).